# Regex to replace non A-Z characters plus specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex (for Javascript) that basically does `/([\s\W])+/g`, with the addition of specific strings (case-insensitive).

Right now I'm doing it like:

```
 var a = 'Test 123 Enterprises PTY-Ltd&Llc.';
 a.toLowerCase()
  .replace('pty','')
  .replace('ltd','')
  .replace('llc','')
  .replace(/([\s\W])+/g, '');

  // Result: 'test123enterprises'
```

Of course, I'd love to be able to wrap this all into one `replace()` method, but I can't find any documentation online on how to achieve this via regex. Is this possible?

Comment: "but I can't find any documentation online on how to allow regex" - what??

Comment: Whoops @Qwertiy, edited :)

Comment: Is it correct that you are replacing only first occurencies of 'pty', 'ltd' and 'llc'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.toLowerCase().replace(/pty|ltd|llc|\W+/g,'');
```

It uses the pipe which is basically an OR operator for regular expressions.

Comment: I must note that `[\s\W]+` makes no sense. Use `\W+`, it really means *any non-alphanumeric and non-underscore symbol*, and includes any whitespace.

Comment: Good point, @stribizhev. I just copied what the OP had without thinking about it. I updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a logical `OR` :

```
/pty|ltd|llc|([\s\W])+/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternation operator `|` to specify alternatives:

```js
var re = /\b(?:pty|ltd|llc)\b|\W+/gi; 
var str = 'Test 123 Enterprises PTY-Ltd&Llc.';
var result = str.replace(re, '').toLowerCase();
alert(result);
```

To remove `pty`, `ltd` and `llc` as whole words, you need to use word boundary `\b`. Also, you need no capturing group since you are not using it. Also, `\W` includes `\s`, no need to repeat it.